# Changing all varchar columns in a SQL Server database to nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update all `varchar` columns in a database to `nvarchar` without losing the data.

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
```

How do I modify this to update the columns it finds and have that reflected throughout the database?

Comment: you don't, you have to create a new table, migrate the data and drop the original.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the SQL Server specific `sys` catalog views, and what I'd do is just simply **create** the T-SQL statements it takes to change those data types - something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.name, s.name, c.name,
    'ALTER TABLE ' + s.name + '.' + t.Name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + c.name + ' NVARCHAR(' + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX'
            WHEN c.max_length > 4000 THEN 'MAX'
            ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10))
        END
    +
    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ');'
         ELSE ') NOT NULL;'
    END
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
WHERE
    ty.name = 'VARCHAR'
    AND c.is_computed = 0
```

Run on the `AdventureWorks` database, this will output something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Sales.SalesOrderHeader ALTER COLUMN CreditCardApprovalCode NVARCHAR(15);
ALTER TABLE Person.Password ALTER COLUMN PasswordHash NVARCHAR(128);
ALTER TABLE Person.Password ALTER COLUMN PasswordSalt NVARCHAR(10);
```

which you can then copy from the output grid into a new query window and execute.

**Note:** running your original script against `AdventureWorks` showed me that in that case, one of the columns is **computed** and can therefore not be modified by simply using a `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ....` statement - that's why I'm excluding computed columns in my script shown here.

If you really insist, you could also turns this SQL statement of mine into the "heart" of a **cursor** and then iterate over the T-SQL statement to modify the table, and execute those using `EXEC(...)` or `EXEC sp_executesql`

Comment: +1 for catching the computed column issue. Currently needs a tiny update to handle `(max)` length, returns `NVARCHAR(-1)`

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: @SqlZim: added support to handle the `VARCHAR(MAX)` case as well

Comment: Alter the `CASE c.max_length` condition: `CASE WHEN c.max_length >4000 OR c.max_length < 0 THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(c.max_length as varchar(5)) + ');'`